# What type of view to embed a Table View and View into

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

I want to have a Table View that occupies the top 5/6ths or so of the screen, and then have a View that occupies the bottom 1/6th of the screen. Xcode won't let me simply drag a View into the Table View (as I already have a static view at the top of the Table View. I'm not really sure why it won't let me do a second one at the bottom...) so I'm setting it up as two separate views located on a single screen. What type of view should I embed the Table View and View in? A Container View? A plain old View? Thanks!

Purpose: I'm trying to create a static View that always stays at the bottom of a Table so I'm setting it up as a separate View below the Table View. Unless there's a better way to get a static View to show up at the bottom of a Table View in addition to the static View I already have at the top of the Table View? I don't want this bottom View to scroll with the Table.

Comment: Have you started from a view controller or a tableviewcontroller in interface builder?

Comment: TableViewController

Comment: That is your problem. Use a view controller, then add your views, including a tableview to that. You can set an aspect ratio constraint between the height of the table and the root view height and set constraints so that the lower view consumes the rest of the space. The root view of a tableviewcontroller is the tableview, and a ViewController only has. A single root view, so you can't add peer views to the tableview and a tableview can't contain subviews